# HP Load runner local web server is not running

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

HP->Load runner->Web Tours->Startserver gives following error:

`httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name
, using 192.168.0.101 for ServerName`

I am unable to connect to load generator due to this.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing.  You refer to an error on the startup of the webtours sample and then reference a load generator issue.  Can you please provide clarification?

Comment: I was following a tutorial to fo load testing using load runner. While working on controller, i needed to add load generator. Tutorial selected localhost server for that. It appeared by default in list in tutorial but it does not appear in my controller cz my local server for load runner was not running.

Comment: If you installed the full package of LoadRunner on the single host that you are using for training, then this installation also includes the components required to be a load generator.   While it is common to use the same host as the controller as a load generator for training purposes, in general use this combination of controller and load generator is considered to be a poor practice